# Jumbotron responsive matching height

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with two Jumbotron within it in two different column and I would like to make the two jumbotron have the same height responsively matching the highest height.

```
<div class="row">
        {% if project.has_member_responses %}
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="jumbotron greenback box-shad">
            <h4>Welcome to the Project test "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="jumbotron doughnut greenback score-box box-shad">
        <div class="score-title">
          <h4>Team Score</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="chart" data-percent="66">
          <div class="score-text">
              <span>77</span>

          </div>

        </div>
```

I gave it a try using Jquery that I found online but with no success :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var jumboMaxHeight = 0

  $(".jumbotron").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > jumboMaxHeight) {
      jumboMaxHeight = $(this).height() }
    })

  $(".jumbotron").height(jumboMaxHeight)

})
  </script>
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jquery.matchheight.js library which is easy to use. All you need to do is apply a css class to the colomns you want to match the height based on the biggest height of them example

```
<div class="col-xs-6 same-height">...
```

and then call the matchHeight() function on that css class.

```
$('.same-height').matchHeight();
```

Here is a codepen example to show you with and without matchheight.js library. You can use the cdn or download the js file and include in your project.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/mXewYW

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put a jumbotron inside rows and columns, it's already a full "row" in itself.

I believe Bootstrap's Cards are better suited for what you're trying to achieve, incidentally they could be made of equal height if put inside a card group: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups